# ssh2 timed out while waiting for handshake

Tags: node.js, ssh, openssh

I am trying to use node.js to issue command line in my Linux servers via ssh. I found this https://github.com/mscdex/ssh2 and tried to test out. Here is my code and `ready` event is never fired:

```
 var Client = require('ssh2').Client;

 console.log('Start ssh2...');
 var conn = new Client();
 conn.on('ready', function() {
    console.log('Client :: ready');
            conn.shell(function(err, stream) {
              if (err) throw err;
              stream.on('close', function() {
                console.log('Stream :: close');
                conn.end();
              }).on('data', function(data) {
                console.log('STDOUT: ' + data);
              }).stderr.on('data', function(data) {
                console.log('STDERR: ' + data);
              });
              stream.end('ls -l\nexit\n');
            });
 }).connect({
   host: '12.12.12.12',
   port: 22,
   tryKeyboard: true,
   debug: console.log,
   readyTimeout: 99999,
   username: 'root',
   password: 'password'
 });
```

I did set long `readyTimeout` and `tryKeyboard` true.

Here is the log:

```
DEBUG: Local ident: 'SSH-2.0-ssh2js0.0.14'
DEBUG: Client: Trying 123.123.123.123 on port 22 ...
DEBUG: Client: Connected
DEBUG: Parser: IN_INIT
DEBUG: Parser: IN_GREETING
DEBUG: Parser: IN_HEADER
DEBUG: Remote ident: 'SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2'
DEBUG: Outgoing: Writing KEXINIT
DEBUG: Parser: IN_PACKETBEFORE (expecting 8)
DEBUG: Parser: IN_PACKET
DEBUG: Parser: pktLen:1540,padLen:7,remainLen:1536
DEBUG: Parser: IN_PACKETDATA
DEBUG: Parser: IN_PACKETDATAAFTER, packet: KEXINIT
DEBUG: Comparing KEXINITs ...
DEBUG: (local) KEX algorithms: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellm
an-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
DEBUG: (remote) KEX algorithms: ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-
nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1
,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
DEBUG: KEX algorithm: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
DEBUG: (local) Host key formats: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
DEBUG: (remote) Host key formats: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
DEBUG: Host key format: ssh-rsa
DEBUG: (local) Client->Server ciphers: aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr,aes128-g
cm,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-cbc,aes192-cb
c,aes128-cbc,blowfish-cbc,3des-cbc,arcfour256,arcfour128,cast128-cbc,arcfour
DEBUG: (remote) Client->Server ciphers: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour
256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc
,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu
.se
DEBUG: Client->Server Cipher: aes256-ctr
DEBUG: (local) Server->Client ciphers: aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr,aes128-g
cm,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-cbc,aes192-cb
c,aes128-cbc,blowfish-cbc,3des-cbc,arcfour256,arcfour128,cast128-cbc,arcfour
DEBUG: (remote) Server->Client ciphers: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour
256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc
,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu
.se
DEBUG: Server->Client Cipher: aes256-ctr
DEBUG: (local) Client->Server HMAC algorithms: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha2-256,
hmac-sha2-256-96,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-512-96,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-sha1-96,hmac
-md5-96
DEBUG: (remote) Client->Server HMAC algorithms: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sh
a1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-25
6-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,h
mac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-
64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,h
mac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
DEBUG: Client->Server HMAC algorithm: hmac-md5
DEBUG: (local) Server->Client HMAC algorithms: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha2-256,
hmac-sha2-256-96,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-512-96,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-sha1-96,hmac
-md5-96
DEBUG: (remote) Server->Client HMAC algorithms: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sh
a1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-25
6-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,h
mac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-
64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,h
mac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
DEBUG: Server->Client HMAC algorithm: hmac-md5
DEBUG: (local) Client->Server compression algorithms: none
DEBUG: (remote) Client->Server compression algorithms: none,zlib@openssh.com
DEBUG: Client->Server compression algorithm: none
DEBUG: (local) Server->Client compression algorithms: none
DEBUG: (remote) Server->Client compression algorithms: none,zlib@openssh.com
DEBUG: Server->Client compression algorithm: none
DEBUG: Outgoing: Writing KEXDH_GEX_REQUEST
DEBUG: Parser: IN_PACKETBEFORE (expecting 8)
DEBUG: Parser: IN_PACKET
DEBUG: Parser: pktLen:404,padLen:8,remainLen:400
DEBUG: Parser: IN_PACKETDATA
DEBUG: Parser: IN_PACKETDATAAFTER, packet: KEXDH_GEX_GROUP
DEBUG: Outgoing: Writing KEXDH_GEX_INIT
DEBUG: Parser: IN_PACKETBEFORE (expecting 8)
DEBUG: Parser: IN_PACKET
DEBUG: Parser: pktLen:956,padLen:7,remainLen:952
DEBUG: Parser: IN_PACKETDATA
DEBUG: Parser: IN_PACKETDATAAFTER, packet: KEXDH_GEX_REPLY
DEBUG: Checking host key format
DEBUG: Checking signature format
DEBUG: Verifying host fingerprint
DEBUG: Host accepted by default (no verification)
DEBUG: Verifying signature
DEBUG: Outgoing: Writing NEWKEYS
DEBUG: Parser: IN_PACKETBEFORE (expecting 8)
DEBUG: Parser: IN_PACKET
DEBUG: Parser: pktLen:12,padLen:10,remainLen:8
DEBUG: Parser: IN_PACKETDATA
DEBUG: Parser: IN_PACKETDATAAFTER, packet: NEWKEYS
DEBUG: Outgoing: Writing SERVICE_REQUEST (ssh-userauth)
DEBUG: Parser: IN_PACKETBEFORE (expecting 16)
DEBUG: Parser: IN_PACKET
DEBUG: Parser: Decrypting
DEBUG: Parser: pktLen:28,padLen:10,remainLen:16
DEBUG: Parser: IN_PACKETDATA
DEBUG: Parser: Decrypting
DEBUG: Parser: HMAC size:16
DEBUG: Parser: IN_PACKETDATAVERIFY
DEBUG: Parser: Verifying MAC
DEBUG: Parser: IN_PACKETDATAVERIFY (Valid HMAC)
DEBUG: Parser: IN_PACKETDATAAFTER, packet: SERVICE_ACCEPT
DEBUG: Outgoing: Writing USERAUTH_REQUEST (password)
DEBUG: Parser: IN_PACKETBEFORE (expecting 16)
DEBUG: Parser: IN_PACKET
DEBUG: Parser: Decrypting
DEBUG: Parser: pktLen:44,padLen:7,remainLen:32
DEBUG: Parser: IN_PACKETDATA
DEBUG: Parser: Decrypting
DEBUG: Parser: HMAC size:16
DEBUG: Parser: IN_PACKETDATAVERIFY
DEBUG: Parser: Verifying MAC
DEBUG: Parser: IN_PACKETDATAVERIFY (Valid HMAC)
DEBUG: Parser: IN_PACKETDATAAFTER, packet: USERAUTH_FAILURE
DEBUG: Client: password auth failed
DEBUG: Outgoing: Writing USERAUTH_REQUEST (keyboard-interactive)
DEBUG: Parser: IN_PACKETBEFORE (expecting 16)
DEBUG: Parser: IN_PACKET
DEBUG: Parser: Decrypting
DEBUG: Parser: pktLen:44,padLen:11,remainLen:32
DEBUG: Parser: IN_PACKETDATA
DEBUG: Parser: Decrypting
DEBUG: Parser: HMAC size:16
DEBUG: Parser: IN_PACKETDATAVERIFY
DEBUG: Parser: Verifying MAC
DEBUG: Parser: IN_PACKETDATAVERIFY (Valid HMAC)
DEBUG: Parser: IN_PACKETDATAAFTER, packet: USERAUTH_INFO_REQUEST
DEBUG: Parser: IN_PACKETBEFORE (expecting 16)
events.js:85
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
            ^
Error: Timed out while waiting for handshake
    at null._onTimeout (\node_modules\ssh2\lib\client.js:138:17)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:110:15)
```

However, if I change ssh server configuration to have private key in my node.js server, it could authenticate. My question is **why username/password authentication doesn't work and how to fix it (either my code or change server configs somehow)?**

Comment: So the `Client` left you hanging? [I'll see myself out]

Comment: Are you actually allowing password based logins on that SSH server? Especially for root, this is often disabled (`PermitRootLogin no` or `PermitRootLogin without-password`). If you try a password based login with a standard SSH client from the application machine, does that work?

Comment: Yes root login works as I have been using Putty on it. I am wondering if there is some way to leave user/pass method but enable something else for this to work. I would hate to create private keys for all servers I have (which are many and could be more)

Comment: You've set `tryKeyboard`, but you haven't added a `keyboard-interactive` event handler to handle the keyboard-interactive requests sent by the server. Typically these requests only ask 'Password:', but not necessarily. Either way, you have to respond to them.

Comment: Do I suppose to just do this `finish(['my_password']);` within `keyboard-interactive`?

Comment: You can try that, *assuming* there is only one prompt *and* it's for the user's password and not something else.